# How to use the JOption on my guessing game?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.*;

public class GuessingGameGUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int value = rand.nextInt(32) + 1;
        int guesses = 0, LowGuess = 0, HighGuess = 0; //ADDED LowGuess AND HighGuess
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int guess;
        boolean win = false;
        while (win == false) {
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Guess a number between 1 and 32: ");
            guess = input.nextInt();
            guesses++;
            if (guess == value) {
                win = true;
            } else if (guess < value) {
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Your guess is lower than random number");
                LowGuess++; //COUNTER TO KEEP TRACK OF LOW GUESSES
            } else if (guess > value) {
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Your guess is higher than random number");
                HighGuess++; //COUNTER TO KEEP TRACK OF HIGH GUESSES
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You win! You are the worst guesser in history!");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The number was: " + value);

// ADDED FROM HERE (GUESSES)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Number of Guesses:" + guesses);
        for (int x = 1; x <= guesses; x++) {
            for (int a = 1; a <= guesses; a++) {
                if (a == guesses) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "*");
                }
            }
        } // TO HERE FOR AMOUNT OF GUESSES

// I ADDED FROM HERE (LOW)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Smaller Guesses:" + LowGuess);
        for (int Low_i = 1; Low_i <= LowGuess; Low_i++) {
            for (int Low_e = 1; Low_e <= LowGuess; Low_e++) {
                if (Low_e == LowGuess) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "*");
                }
            }
        } // Then TO HERE FOR LOW

// I ADDED FROM HERE (HIGH)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Largest Guesses:" + HighGuess);
        for (int High_i = 1; High_i <= HighGuess; High_i++) {
            for (int High_e = 1; High_e <= HighGuess; High_e++) {
                if (High_e == HighGuess) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "*");
                }
            }
        } //FINALLY TO HERE FOR HIGH
    }
}
```

// when I run my program the message box pops up when i enter my guessing number, however it seems to stop and nothing else pops up to let me know if i guessed to high or to low.

Answer (score 0):

Take these lines, for example:

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Guess a number between 1 and 32: ");
guess = input.nextInt();
```

A prompt displays that asks you to "Guess a number between 1 and 32". So you enter the number, and then execution stops because your `Scanner` is awaiting your input. You need to completely remove your Scanner so you won't have these frequent interruptions.

The `showInputDialog` method of `JOptionPane` returns a `String`, as shown in the example from the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html):

> Show a dialog asking the user to type in a String:
>
> ```
> String inputValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input a value");
> ```

As is, you're throwing away the value returned from the method when you should instead be assigning it to your variables. In order to assign the returned value to your `int` variable `guess`, use `Integer.parseInt`:

```
guess = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Guess a number between 1 and 32: "));
```

Answer (score 0):

JOptionPane.showInputDialog returns String than you have to convert that String to int using Parse methods, every time you receive input.

String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog();

Int number = Integer.parseInt(input);